# If there is data in any of A - F cells, copy that data into G cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Can anyone assist with this formula? I need to have data (number) copied into a cell from any of the other 10 cells. For example, I have 10 cells all of which might have data in them (only one cell of 10 will have data) and I need a formula that checks those 10 cells and inserts that data into the 11th cell. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: A to F is only 6 not 10?

Comment: What is the type of this data?  Is it numeric?

Comment: you need to look at the CONCATENATE function within excel, that will pretty much solve your problem

Comment: It's actually B-K and I need to insert the data into A. It's numeric (currency).

Comment: How can you guarantee only one cell within a row range will have data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you two solutions that could work.

First Concatenate as per Nabil Aziz comment.  Since all other cells are blank it doesn't join anything else to the cell that has something in it returning just the one value.  Since concatenate returns a string using *1 will transform it back into a number

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1)*1
```

Another option is to find the cell and just return that.

If you are always using text you can use

```
=OFFSET(A1,0,MATCH("*",A1:F1,-1)-1)
```

Which finds the **last** cell with text in the range A1:F1 and offsets that much from cell A1

If you are using all numbers you can use

```
=OFFSET(A1,0,MATCH(1E+306,A1:F1,1)-1)
```

Which works the same way.  If you don't know if it will be text or numbers you could use

```
=OFFSET(A1,0,IFERROR(MATCH(1E+306,A1:F1,1),MATCH("*",A1:F1,-1))-1)
```

Which will find the last number if there is one and the last text entry if no number is there.

All these solutions can be copied down.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is numeric data, the `SUM` function is probably the best. It sounds like you want to put this in your first column:

```
=SUM(B1:K1)
```

This will actually add the columns instead of treating the data as text.